# Text file reader not reading until end of file

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the following text file that I use the position and length as a rule to get a substring value of a give string.

```
    ID   A      B   Element Name                    Element    C    Length  Position Key2

    01  PN    PNFN  USER MID NAM                    USR        1      1         2      A

    ....about 60 rows
```

Here is my how I am reading the the text file and apply the position and length value of the text file
to the string input.

string input = "AAAAABBBBCCCCDDDDGGGG......"

```
**EDIT**
     var values = File.ReadLines("file")
        .SkipWhile(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace).Skip(1)
                          .Select(l => l.Split(new[] {' ', '\t'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
          var array1 = offsets.Select(split => new
                 {
                     Element = split[5],
                     Length = int.Parse(split[7]),
                     Position = int.Parse(split[8])
                 });

     foreach (var info in array1)
        {
            string substring = input.Substring(info.Position, info.Length);

            Console.WriteLine("Element: '{0}' Value: '{1}'", info.Element, substring);
        }
```

This will read only 14 rows and it breaks the loop. Is there anything I am doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: you may have some missing columns in some lines.try removing `Where` and see how many lines will you get

Comment: in the given example you have 10 column headers and row has 11 values so it will fail on `split.Length == 10`

Comment: @Selman22 removing where throws:Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct f
ormat.

Comment: @dkozl I removed the area that part that checks split.Length. please see my edit

Answer (score 0):

I used a sub string instead of a space to find the exact location:

```
       foreach (var hashtable in from item in offsets
                                                 let element = item.Substring(4,2)
                                                 let length = Convert.ToInt32(item.Substring(6, 6))
                                                 let position = item.Substring(7, 4)
                                                 select new Hashtable
                                                     {
                                                         {"Element", element},
                                                         {"Length", length},
                                                         {"Position", position}
                                                     })
```